# enable vertical touch scroll on position:absolute div

Tags: css, cordova, scroll

I recreated the problem and it looks similar to the fiddle below.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35H5c/)**

How can I make the `class="content"` vertically touch scrollable ?

For testing, you can use the chrome emulation tools to emulate touch events.

<kbd>f12</kbd> -> <kbd>esc</kbd> -> emulation tab -> sensors -> emulate touch screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i think your app is top and bottom fixed. you need scroll content only so you need [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) plugin just add this